# Модальное окно с использование куки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Это исходный код модального окна, которое постоянно выскакивает при загрузке страницы.

Нужно что бы результаты сохранялись в куки: если пользователь нажимает на `Yes` его пропускает дальше, если `No` то редирект на google.com
Если пользователь ставит отметку в чекбоксе `Remember Me` то сохранить это значение в куках, чтоб при следующем входе этот попап не появлялся.

```
            <div class="verification-popup-wrapper">
                <div class="verification-popup">

                    <div class="popup-contents-wrapper">
                        <i class="close"></i>
                        <h2>Welcome to Website!</h2>
                        <div class="popup-content">
                            <p>To continue, please confirm your age.</p>
                            <p>Are you 21+?</p>
                        </div>
                        <form class="age-gate-form">  
                          <button type="button" value="yes" class="age-gate-submit-yes" name="confirm">Yes</button>
                          <button type="button" value="no" class="age-gate-submit-no" name="confirm">No</button>
                          <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="remember" value="remember">
                            <label for="rememberMe">Remember me</label>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Я подключил библиотеку, и повешал куку на событие click

```
jQuery('.age-gate-submit-yes').click(function() {
    if(jQuery("#rememberMe").prop('checked')) {  
        jQuery.cookie('hide_popup', 1);
    }
    jQuery(this).parents('.verification-popup-wrapper').fadeOut();
})
```

Вроде все работает. Пока искал решение попал на [готовый пример](https://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Website-Age-Verification-Plugin-with-jQuery.html), но без чекбокса

Comment: и чего надо то вам от js/jquery. отправляете форму на сервер, вот на сервере и пропишите эти куки. и диалог выводите в завивисмости от этих кук.

Comment: да, извините, я неправильно описал, сейчас поправил. Само сохранение результатов в куки меня интересует

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кстати не обязательно отправлять форму на север, вы вполне можете записать куку и с помощью JS. Кстати в интернете уже давно написаны удобные функции, поэтому изобретать велосипед не стоит.

```
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {   
    document.cookie = name+'=; Max-Age=-99999999;';  
}
```

Допустим, добавим куку test со значением "1", которая будет хранится 7 дней:

```
setCookie('test', '1', 7);
```

Получить куку:

```
var count = getCookie('test');
```

Теперь просто при нажатии на кнопку "нет" делайте редирект на google.ru, а при нажатии на "да", закрывайте окно и добавляйте куку. Ну соответственно при открытии сайта проверяйте наличие куки.

Если нужно решение на jQuery, то для это есть библиотека https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie, которая ещё сильнее упростит процесс.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю. А я разве писал что-то об отправке формы на сервер? Меня устраивает, если они будут храниться в JS

Comment: @eugene_v тем не менее, `<form>`  у вас описан, что подразумевает отправку на сервер.

Comment: понял, исправлю

Comment: Я прочитал комментарий на вопрос про отправку на сервер и поэтому предложил альтернативный вариант. А куки хранятся в браузере, независимо от способа их добавления, хранится в js они не могут.

Comment: Ну для меня методы GET и POST еще не очевидные вещи, мне еще придется освоить эти вещи, поэтому простите за нубство. Да и JS на ВЫ и шепотом

Comment: @eugene_v у вас получилось?

Comment: неа ))) еще разбираюсь, я уже перелопатил, ух...

Comment: в общем я подключил библиотеку и на событие click повешал куку

Comment: Кстати, попутный вопрос, вы указали 7 - это 7 дней, а на сайте learn.javascript.ru указано в секундах expires: 3600, а как скрипт определяет в днях это или в секундах?

Comment: @eugene_v именно в этом варианте указывать нужно дни, вообще в интернете есть несколько вариантов. Однако мне удобней указывать дни, чем секунды.

Comment: ну мне нужно сейчас сделать, чтоб при нажатии на Yes кука жила 2 часа, поэтому здесь конечно удобнее будет указать 7200 сек